# std::sort using function as comparator, not working?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm having trouble understanding why this doesn't sort the vector by the time/size of the DirObj....the relevant part of the code I'm struggling with is just below, but I've also put the full code for this project (3 files) below that.

edit: I should probably clarify, it does appear to move things around, but the end result is not ordered or reverse ordered, and seems unrelated to the property I'm trying to sort by.

Relevant part:

```
sortBy() {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), byTime);
    std::cout << "Sorted by time:" << std::endl;
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << **it;
    }
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), bySize);
    std::cout << "Sorted by size:" << std::endl;
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << **it;
        delete *it;
    }
}

bool byTime(DirObj * x, DirObj * y) {
    return ( ((x->getStat()).st_size) < ((y->getStat()).st_size) );
}

bool bySize(DirObj * x, DirObj * y) {
    return ( ((x->getStat()).st_atime) < ((y->getStat()).st_atime) );
}
```

Traversal.cpp

```
/* A file traversal program for the Unix filesystem. */
/* Allows the user to select one of the following options:
    depth-first-order (stack)
    breadth-first-order (queue)
    Sort by size */

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "DirObj.h"
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void printUsage();
void breadthFirst(const std::string);
void depthFirstR(const std::string);
void depthFirstNR(const std::string);
void sortBy(const std::string);
bool byTime(DirObj *, DirObj *);
bool bySize(DirObj *, DirObj *);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string buffer;
    int cnt;

    /* input validation, check for too few arguments */
    if (argc < 3) {
        printUsage();
        return 1;
    }

    /* get directory pathname */
    buffer = argv[2];
    buffer.append("/");


    /* check for options */
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-a") == 0) {
        breadthFirst(buffer);
        std::cout << std::endl << "Recursive depth-first traversal of " << buffer << ":" << std::endl;
        depthFirstR(buffer);
        depthFirstNR(buffer);
        sortBy(buffer);
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "-b") == 0) {
        breadthFirst(buffer);
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0) {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Recursive depth-first traversal of " << buffer << ":" << std::endl;
        depthFirstR(buffer);
        depthFirstNR(buffer);
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "-s") == 0) {
        sortBy(buffer);
    }
    else {
        printUsage();
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "DONE. All requested traversals were successful." << std::endl;   

    return 0;
}

void printUsage() {
        printf("Usage: ./dirTraverse <mode> <directory pathname>\n");
        printf("   Modes:\n");
        printf("   -a   All traversals\n");
        printf("   -b   Breadth-first\n");
        printf("   -d   Depth-first\n");
        printf("   -s   Sort by size\n");
        printf("   -t   Sort by time\n");
        return;
}

/* uses a queue */
void breadthFirst(const std::string b) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "Breadth-first traversal of " << b << ":" << std::endl;

    struct dirent *d;
    DIR *dir;
    struct stat stat_b;
    std::string buffer;
    buffer = b;

    std::queue<DirObj *> q;
    DirObj * o;

    /* open the initial directory */
    dir = opendir(buffer.c_str());
    if (!dir) {
        std::cout << "Could not open " << buffer << "." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        /* push all directory entries onto queue */
        while ((d = readdir(dir))) {
            q.push(new DirObj(d, buffer));
        }
        // closedir(dir);
    }

    /* dequeue each directory entry and print */
    while (!q.empty()) {
        o = q.front();
        q.pop();
        std::cout << *o;
        d = o->getEntry();
        stat_b = o->getStat();
        /* if the entry is a directory (but not . or ..) */
        if (S_ISDIR(stat_b.st_mode) && (strcmp(d->d_name, "..") != 0) && (strcmp(d->d_name, ".") != 0)) {
            buffer = o->getPath();
            buffer.append(d->d_name);
            /* open directory */
            dir = opendir(buffer.c_str());
            if (!dir) {
                std::cout << "Could not open " << buffer << "." << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                /* push all directory entries onto queue */
                buffer.append("/");
                while ((d = readdir(dir))) {
                    q.push(new DirObj(d, buffer));
                }
                // closedir(dir);
            }

        }
        delete o;

    }
}

/* recursive, works, very basic */
void depthFirstR(const std::string b) {    
    struct dirent *d;
    DIR *dir;
    struct stat stat_b;
    std::string buffer = b;
    int l = buffer.length();

    /* open initial directory */
    dir = opendir(buffer.c_str());
    if (!dir) {
        std::cout << "Could not open " << buffer << "." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        /* while there are directory entries, read the next one and print it */
        while ((d = readdir(dir))) {
            buffer.append(d->d_name);
            stat(buffer.c_str(), &stat_b);
            std::cout << buffer << " : {inode=" << d->d_ino << ", size=" << stat_b.st_size << ", time=" << stat_b.st_atime << "}" << std::endl;
            /* if the directory entry is a directory, recursively traverse it */
            if (S_ISDIR(stat_b.st_mode) && (strcmp(d->d_name, "..") != 0) && (strcmp(d->d_name, ".") != 0)) {
                buffer.append("/");
                depthFirstR(buffer);
            }
            buffer = buffer.substr(0, l);
        }
        // closedir(dir);
    }
}

/* non-recursive, uses an explicit stack of DirObj to keep track of paths associated with dirents */
void depthFirstNR(const std::string b) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "Non-recursive depth-first traversal of " << b << ":" << std::endl;

    struct dirent *d;
    DIR *dir;
    struct stat stat_b;
    std::string buffer = b;

    DirObj *o;
    std::stack<DirObj *> s;    

    /* open the initial directory */
    dir = opendir(buffer.c_str());
    if (!dir) {
        std::cout << "Could not open " << buffer << "." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        /* push all directory entries onto stack */
        while ((d = readdir(dir))) {
            s.push(new DirObj(d, buffer));
        }
        // closedir(dir);
    }

    /* pop each directory entry off stack and print */
    while (!s.empty()) {
        o = s.top();
        s.pop();
        std::cout << *o;
        d = o->getEntry();
        stat_b = o->getStat();
        /* if the entry is a directory (but not . or ..) */
        if (S_ISDIR(stat_b.st_mode) && (strcmp(d->d_name, "..") != 0) && (strcmp(d->d_name, ".") != 0)) {
            /* open directory */
            buffer = o->getPath();
            buffer.append(d->d_name);
            dir = opendir(buffer.c_str());
            if (!dir) {
                std::cout << "Could not open " << buffer << "." << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                /* push all directory entries onto stack */
                buffer.append("/");
                while ((d = readdir(dir))) {
                    s.push(new DirObj(d, buffer));
                }
                // closedir(dir);
            }
        }
        delete o;
    }
}


void sortBy(const std::string b) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "Sorted by size/time traversal of " << b << ":" << std::endl;

    struct dirent *d;
    DIR *dir;
    struct stat stat_b;
    std::string buffer = b;

    DirObj * o;
    std::stack<DirObj *> s;
    std::vector<DirObj *> v;  

    /* open the initial directory */
    dir = opendir(buffer.c_str());
    if (!dir) {
        std::cout << "Could not open " << buffer << "." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        /* push all directory entries onto stack */
        while ((d = readdir(dir))) {
            s.push(new DirObj(d, buffer));
        }
        // closedir(dir);
    }

    /* pop each directory entry off stack and print */
    while (!s.empty()) {
        o = s.top();
        s.pop();
        v.push_back(o);
        d = o->getEntry();
        stat_b = o->getStat();
        /* if the entry is a directory (but not . or ..) */
        if (S_ISDIR(stat_b.st_mode) && (strcmp(d->d_name, "..") != 0) && (strcmp(d->d_name, ".") != 0)) {
            /* open directory */
            buffer = o->getPath();
            buffer.append(d->d_name);
            dir = opendir(buffer.c_str());
            if (!dir) {
                std::cout << "Could not open " << buffer << "." << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                /* push all directory entries onto stack */
                buffer.append("/");
                while ((d = readdir(dir))) {
                    s.push(new DirObj(d, buffer));
                }
                // closedir(dir);
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<DirObj *>::iterator it;
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), byTime);
    std::cout << "Sorted by time:" << std::endl;
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << **it;
    }
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), bySize);
    std::cout << "Sorted by size:" << std::endl;
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << **it;
        delete *it;
    }
}

bool byTime(DirObj * x, DirObj * y) {
    return ( ((x->getStat()).st_size) < ((y->getStat()).st_size) );
}

bool bySize(DirObj * x, DirObj * y) {
    return ( ((x->getStat()).st_atime) < ((y->getStat()).st_atime) );
}
```

DirObj.h

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

class DirObj {

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, DirObj &obj);

    private:
        dirent * entry;
        std::string path;
        struct stat stat_b;

    public:
        DirObj(dirent * e, const std::string p);
        DirObj();
        ~DirObj();
        DirObj(const DirObj &rhs);
        DirObj& operator=(const DirObj &rhs);
        std::string getPath() const;
        dirent * getEntry() const;
        struct stat getStat() const;
};
```

DirObj.cpp

```
#include "DirObj.h"

DirObj::DirObj(dirent * e = 0, const std::string p = "\0") {
    entry = e;
    path = p;
    std::string buffer = path;
    buffer.append(entry->d_name);
    stat(buffer.c_str(), &stat_b);
}

DirObj::DirObj() {
    entry = 0;
    path = "\0";
}

DirObj::~DirObj() {

}

DirObj::DirObj(const DirObj &rhs) {
    this->entry = rhs.entry;
    this->path = rhs.path;
    this->stat_b = rhs.stat_b;
}

DirObj& DirObj::operator=(const DirObj &rhs) {
    this->entry = rhs.entry;
    this->path = rhs.path;
    this->stat_b = rhs.stat_b;
    return *this;
}

std::string DirObj::getPath() const {
    return path;
}

dirent * DirObj::getEntry() const {
    return entry;
}

struct stat DirObj::getStat() const {
    return stat_b;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, DirObj &obj) {
    out << obj.path << (obj.entry)->d_name << ": {inode=" << (obj.entry)->d_ino << ", size=" << (obj.stat_b).st_size << ", time=" << (obj.stat_b).st_atime << "}" << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Can you please distil the code down to the actual problem area, and provide an example output and input

Comment: You should swap the names of the both functions `byTime` and `bySize` (you mixed the properties to sort by).

Comment: `struct stat getStat() const;` should be `stat getStat() const;`

Comment: @hochl, you are right.... /facepalm. I should probably also take a break. ;) Thank you! If you submit an answer I'll select it.

Comment: Also, both `byTime` and `bySize` are called when passing the `-s` option, and the `-t` option you list in the usage does not exist.

Comment: Such things happen, no problem. I've submitted an answer :^)

Comment: For the future: this answer deserves negative reputation. The *relevant* parts are impossible to read, the function has no return value, the declaration of `v` (most important thing is the type) is not present in the code and on the contrary there is a lot of irrelevant code in the question.

Comment: @g24l: Two comments, and both wrong. I have to agree that in the first case, without the type of `v` it is not clear, but if you read the code it is kind of obvious that it is a container (vector most probably) of pointers, so you are actually recommending to leak memory. Before jumping to recommendations, make sure you understand the code, and if it is not clear, do ask in a comment. In the second case, the `struct` is not required, but it is not wrong either.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas , I think your comment is a bit offensive. I would like to ask you what code review means to you? Your claim is that you can write it like this because is legal. Well you can, but the homework's mark will be less, at least in my class.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas , btw you contradict yourself ... "he declaration of `v` (most important thing is the type) is not present in the code " and the you say that we should read carefully????!??

Comment: @g24l: Sorry if I offended you, I did not mean to, seriously. I find that there is a difference between requesting that the type is made explicit in the question (that is an issue with the question) and claiming that *delete *it; is obsolete, dies when going out of scope*. Well, it does not because they are pointers, which you could have guessed from the code (no guessing should be needed if the question had it!). My claim here is that the question should be clearer, and that you should not suggest a change that you don't know whether it is right or wrong (and it is wrong in this case).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas , ok non-taken,  `delete *it` is not, I just noticed it . I must have been upset at the time, and seen `delete it`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should swap the names of the both functions byTime and bySize (you mixed the properties to sort by). Fixed version:

```
bool byTime(DirObj * x, DirObj * y) {
    return ( ((x->getStat()).st_atime) < ((y->getStat()).st_atime) );
}

bool bySize(DirObj * x, DirObj * y) {
    return ( ((x->getStat()).st_size) < ((y->getStat()).st_size) );
}
```